# IONIC 3rd party libs

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, ionic2, phaser-framework, p5.js

I'm new to ionic and need a little help:

I have implemented things like chart.js with the tutorial from [here](https://www.joshmorony.com/adding-responsive-charts-graphs-to-ionic-2-applications/), and I really liked the outcome.

But I tried to do the same thing with **p5.js** from [processing](https://p5js.org/) and could not get it to work.

I have to display data for a class on Data Visualization and want to use Ionic with **mo.js**, **p5.js**, or **phaser.js** to display the data.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need the p5 library from somewhere. The easiest way here is npm. So install p5 using npm:

```
npm install p5
```

Then you need to import the library from `node_modules` so webpack knows it should put it in your `vendor.js` bundle:

```
import * as p5 from 'p5/lib/p5.min';
```

Then you can use it like that:

```
let sketch = p => {
  let x = 100;
  let y = 100;

  p.setup = () => {
    p.createCanvas(700, 410);
  };

  p.draw = () => {
    p.background(0);
    p.fill(255);
    p.rect(x, y, 50, 50);
  };
};

let myp5 = new p5(sketch);
```

I have to admit I do not know anything about p5 itself so I can not tell you if it is even a good idea to use it in an ionic project or if the example code on how to use it produces something useable, it is just an example I found on github. I verified that it is working by checking if it created a canvas element and it did create one with the dimension defined in the example (it was created as a sibling element of the ion-app element):

```
<canvas id="defaultCanvas0" style="width: 700px; height: 410px;" width="2100" height="1230"></canvas>
```

Comment: That was super close, unfortunately I cant get anything to appear inside of the canvas element on the ionic page.

Comment: Well you will probably have to play around a bit with the library to figure out how to actually render something but I can't help you with that.

Answer (score 0):

You still have to render the template into the DOM, but you can use [Renderer2](https://angular.io/api/core/Renderer2) to render an element [ElementRef](https://angular.io/api/core/ElementRef) (`private el: ElementRef`) to the DOM and then attach the p5 instance to the `el` element (`this.el.nativeElement`).

This works for me:

```
import { Component, OnInit, ElementRef, Renderer2 } from '@angular/core';

import * as p5 from 'p5';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-p5',
  templateUrl: './p5.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./p5.page.scss'],
})
export class P5Page implements OnInit {

  constructor(
    private el: ElementRef,
    private renderer: Renderer2
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {

    new p5(p => {
      let x = 100;
      let y = 100;

      p.setup = () => {
        p.createCanvas(700, 410);
      };

      p.draw = () => {
        p.background(0);
        p.fill(255);
        p.rect(x, y, 50, 50);
      };
    }, this.el.nativeElement);

  }
}
```

Of course you need to run `npm install p5` and perhaps also `npm install @types/p5` first.